# Does RESTeasy client support TLS/SSL?

Tags: rest, ssl, https, resteasy

I'm using several RESTful webservice in JAVA based web-application. I'm using the RESTeasy client to access my webservice. Here all communication between the client and service is through XML(JAX-B xml annotated detail classes). Here are the following codes

```
String serviceURL  = "https://service.company.com/Service/getService"

ServiceRequestDetail serviceRequestDetail = getServiceRequestAsDetailClass();
ServiceResponseDetail serviceResponseDetail = new ServiceResponseDetail();
ClientRequest clientRequest = new ClientRequest(serviceURL);
clientRequest.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);   
clientRequest.body(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, serviceRequestDetail);
ClientResponse<ServiceRequestDetail> response =
  clientRequest.post(ServiceRequestDetail.class);

if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + 
                             response.getStatus());
}

ServiceResponseDetail serviceResponseDetail =
  response.getEntity(ServiceResponseDetail.class);
```

and when I try to access my service I get the "Peer not Authenticated" error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
...
```

Is there any way to add the SSL configuration details in the RESTeasy client? any other suggestions for solving this issue is also welcome

Thanks in advance

Comment: People tend to not answer your questions if they see you have never accepted an answer, something to keep in mind (No, I don't know the answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the answer but I'm really sorry for the late response.

To answer my question, RESTeasy client does support TLS/SSL. Infact the problem was I missed to install the certificate into the JVM.

```
keytool -import -alias <Replace certificate Alias name> -keystore $JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\cacerts -file <Replace your Certificate file location>
```

This solved the issue of "Peer Not Authenticated". Hope it helps. Kudos

Comment: though note it has to be a certificate, not just key pair in pem: openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add certificate to JVM and keep this cert separate. You can load the cert as part of your code like below.

```
    // load the certificate
    InputStream fis = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("file/path/to/your/certificate.crt");
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(fis);

    // load the keystore that includes self-signed cert as a "trusted" entry
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("cert-alias", cert);
    tmf.init(keyStore);
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);`
```

then attach to rest easy builder like

`resteasyClientBuilder.sslContext(sslContext)`